# Calculate content length POST

Tags: http, post

How can I calculate content length for example of:

```
POST /Upload/ HTTP/1.1
Host: test.lan
User-Agent: Shockwave Flash
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: text/*
Content-Length: ?????
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------4d2179e6b3c0

------------------------------4d2179e6b3c0
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Filename"

phpinfo.php
------------------------------4d2179e6b3c0
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ASPSESSID"

6e223eb1c7561e9c599f03cc04e9444b
------------------------------4d2179e6b3c0
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Filedata"; filename="phpinfo.php"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

<? phpinfo(); ?>
------------------------------4d2179e6b3c0
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Upload"

Submit Query
------------------------------4d2179e6b3c0--
```

Answer (score 18):

The `Content-Length` value should be calculated by totaling all data *after* the termination of the message headers. In the case of your example, this is everything after this point (with `CRLF` characters included for readability):

```
...
Content-Length: ?????\r\n
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------4d2179e6b3c0\r\n
\r\n
```

Everything coming after the first empty line (`\r\n`) -- including your boundary delimiters -- should be counted in the total length. In practice, this usually means that you'll need to tabulate the `Content-Length` header value  after generating the full message entity body. Once you have the full body of the message you can prepend it with your headers to create the full HTTP message.

According to the HTTP spec you aren't technically *required* to specify the `Content-Length` header. From [RFC 2616 14.13](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13):

> Applications SHOULD use this field to indicate the transfer-length of the message-body, unless this is prohibited by the rules in section 4.4.

However, this is a pretty standard requirement for most servers which will generally send back an error response if the `Content-Length` is missing or incorrectly specified.

Comment: Yes, as per HTTP it is not mandatory requirement but some CGI implementations require a content-length in all POST transactions.

Comment: I don't see a method to calculate Content-Length.